# Unit of maximum resident set size in the output of time

Tags: macos, memory-usage

Can someone let me know what is the unit of maximum resident size in the output below?-

```
/usr/bin/time -l mvn clean package -T 7 -DskipTests
...
real       530.51
user       837.49
sys         64.28
3671834624  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
   2113909  page reclaims
     26733  page faults
         0  swaps
      5647  block input operations
     26980  block output operations
        15  messages sent
        25  messages received
       687  signals received
    406533  voluntary context switches
   1319461  involuntary context switches
```

I am trying to measure peak memory usage of a process.

Environment - Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.5 )

Comment: [Maximum resident set size does not make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035232/maximum-resident-set-size-does-not-make-sense)

Comment: @Seth - Do you meant to say it is bytes?

Comment: Yes but the answer to that question hints that it might be an inaccurate number.

Comment: It does look like bytes. I compared it to zsh `time` and it seem to match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on operating system. On OS X, this is in units of bytes. Here's what the manpage says about this:

```
     -l      The contents of the rusage structure are printed as well.
```

Now, to figure out what that means, run `man getrusage 2`. It says this:

```
     ru_maxrss    the maximum resident set size utilized (in bytes).
```

So the man page says this is in units of bytes.

To double-check the docs, I wrote a test program in C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int mb = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("allocating %d MB", mb);
    int len = mb * 1000 * 1000;
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    memset(buf, 'X', len);
    return 0;
}
```

This reads a command line parameter and allocates that many megabytes. Here's the program in action:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l ./test 1 2>&1 |  grep max   
             1744896  maximum resident set size
$ /usr/bin/time -l ./test 2 2>&1 |  grep max
             2744320  maximum resident set size
```

Allocating one extra megabyte of memory allocates 999424 more units of memory. There is some measurement inaccuracy, but this shows that the unit used is bytes.

I said before that this is OS dependent. On Linux, `ru_maxrss` is in units of kibibytes. Be careful about writing cross-platform code which depends on this.

Answer (score -1):

It is in bytes.
So in this case 3671834624 equals to 3.6 GB.